# Access Bucket File from Perl in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: perl, google-app-engine

How does one open file in a Bucket from Perl program running in a Google Cloud Shell running in the same project?

One can upload a file into the shell file system and open it and also put the file in a bucket for access by others but that seems counter-productive never mind that the files will be out of sync a day later.

I've tried various forms of

`open($fh, '<', "gs://bucketname/filename");`

without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mount the bucket into the file system with fuse.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)